# How to update a merged Matrix?

Tags: javascript

Tried coding Tetris using Canvas. Now i got stuck at the collision detection part.

Got 2 different matrices: one for the specific piece, one for my map.
To detect collision later on, i wanted to merge the piece matrix into the map and update it.

Merging worked well like that:

```js
//merge player matrix into map matrix and return mergedMap
function mergeMatrix(map, matrix, row, column) {
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      map[column+i][row+j] = matrix[i][j];
    }
  }
  return map;
}
```

Updating that Matrix in my animation loop makes it update too fast and it throws errors.

How can i update my merged matrix properly with the constantly updating movements of my pieces?
Can provide more pics of my code if needed ofc.

Comment: Never post pictures of code. Provide a [mre].